# How to add actionlistener to textfield in Java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield, bluej

so this is the concept: Simply, there's a textbox with "Name" as the value, and I wanted that if I click anywhere IN the textbox, the value "Name" will disappear. This is what I've done in my code:

```
JTextField t1 = new JTextField("Name", 10);

t1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent cl){
                t1.setText(" ");
            }
        });
```

There's no syntax errors but when I run the program and clicked somewhere in the textbox, nothing happens and the value "Name" is still there

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. `t1` should be `final` to be accessed in the inner class.

Comment: I accidentally excluded final, sorry for that. But in my program, it is: final JTextField t1 = new JTextField("Name", 10);

Comment: 1)`ActionListener` called after you press `ENTER` key on `JTextField` 2)In 1.8 it can be declared without `final`.
What you try to achive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
t1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        t1.setText(null); // Empty the text field when it receives focus
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, I just added the focusLost event to give t1 the value "Name" again which is cool.

Comment: Question though, what's the purpose of '@Override'? I removed it and the program runs just fine

Comment: @Override annotation in Java is optional but helpful. It defines we are using a new method or overriding an existing method. You can read Method Overriding topic of java to get a clear idea. Thanks

Comment: @RexEndozo: See [*Overriding and Hiding Methods*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

Comment: When I type in a value and then the focus is lost, the textbox sets the value again to "Name" which is bad. How do I make it so that the focusgained t1.setText(null); fire only Once(When the program starts)?

Comment: @RexEndozo you can either write what you want to do after focus is lost in public void focusLost(FocusEvent e){} method.
if you want your listener to work only once you can try this.
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
  if(t1.getText().equals("Name"))
  {
   t1.setText(null); // Empty the text field when it receives focus
  }
  else
  {
   //do nothing;
  }
    }

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use an ActionListener for this purpose. Instead of that the FocusListener should work for you, explained here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextFieldaddFocusListenerFocusListenerl.htm

Comment: I've tried this 't1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener(){
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
                t1.setText("");
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                
            }
        });' but when I run the program, the value "Name" doesn't appear at all

Comment: Try using the other method as following:
public void focusLos(FocusEvent e) {
  t1.setText("Name");
}
And make the textfield not requesting focus on startup!

Comment: @RexEndozo `but when I run the program, the value "Name" doesn't appear at all`, seems that happens because your `JTextField` gain focus at start.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ActionListener, it isn't implementing classes for your needs. You can also add MouseListener by:

```
t1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){...});
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html